# Create a new node.js process per page

Tags: node.js

I am pretty sure this question is asked a lot but cannot find the right search terms to find the answer.

Let's say I have a site, `example.com` and I have two pages, `example.com/game1.html` and `example.com/game2.html`

I would like to host two node.js processes to listen to requests to these pages (where both games require different code). I also want to be able to upgrade these processes without shutting a main process down.

I suspect it has something to do with creating a "main" node process and then redirecting these page calls to the right process. Is there a good module for this?

Comment: sounds like you want to use child process https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a

Comment: why not host two node process independently of one another and use an API gateway (A.K.A. microservices)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to direct two URLs such as:

```
http://example.com/game1.html
http://example.com/game2.html
```

to separate servers is to use a proxy such as [NGINX](https://nginx.org/en/).  The proxy runs on example.com and port 80 so it gets all the requests.  Your other servers run locally on separate ports (no need for them to be directly reachable by the public).  You configure NGINX so that when it sees `http://example.com/game1.html` the request is forwarded to your first server on whatever port it is running on.  When it sees `http://example.com/game2.html` the request is forwarded to your second server on whatever other port it is running on.

After installing NGINX, all of this logic can be configured through its configuration file.

Comment: Yea this makes sense. I can run my node.js on localhost and then point nginx at it. Do you have any article on how I can dynamically upgrade NGINX without killing all requests?

Comment: @MathematicalRain - What do you  mean "dynamically upgrade NGINX"?  I thought you want to upgrade your node.js servers?  There's no single server that you can upgrade while keeping existing requests connected.  You would need some sort of cluster for that where you shut off all new requests from one server in the cluster and then when it's request count gets to zero, you can then take it down with no impact, bring it back up, add it back to the cluster and then repeat with the other elements of the cluster.

Comment: When I want to include a new node.js "game page" I would have to update the NGINX configuration, but I don't want it to shutdown and drop my connections. But I found another answer on this question - https://serverfault.com/questions/378581/nginx-config-reload-without-downtime

Comment: You can upgrade Nginx on the fly without dropping client connections. - see https://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html